# Controling xlim in plot

Tags: r, plot

My example :

```
x = c(1:15)
y = c(-4:10)
plot(x, y)
```

R gives `xlim` automatically as : `2, 4, 6, ..., 14`

How can I change it for : `1, 2, 3,..., 15`

I've tried :

```
my.limits = as.numeric(seq(1, 15, by = 1))
x = c(1:15)
y = c(-4:10)
plot(x, y, ylim = c(-4,10), xlim = my.limits)
```

But with error :

```
Erreur dans plot.window(...) : valeur 'xlim' incorrecte
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the ticks manually like this:

```
x=c(1:15)
y=c(-4:10)
plot(x,y, xaxt="n", xlim = c(1,15)) 
axis(1, at = 1:15)
```

`axt="n"` omits drawing a x-axis in `plot`, first. `axis` manually draws it afterwards - you got more control this way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to lukeA's answer and using the `my.limits` sequence from your code:

```
# Tick marks every 1 unit:
my.limits = as.numeric(seq(1, 15, by = 1))
x=c(1:15)
y=c(-4:10)
plot(x,y, xaxt="n", xlim = c(1,15)) 
axis(1, at = my.limits)

# Tick marks every 5 units:
my.limits = as.numeric(seq(0, 100, by = 5))
x=c(1:100)
y=c(-49:50)
plot(x,y, xaxt="n", xlim = c(1,100)) 
axis(1, at = my.limits)
```